# FindFirstFile skipping a directory

Tags: windows, winapi, directory

Ok, this is making me crazy.  I'm writing a simple program that walks down the directory tree looking at the sizes of all files on my drive.  Pretty tame stuff.

But I noticed that I wasn't getting the answer I expected.  Turns out my code is *skipping* some directories.  To start, here's a (simplified) version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
  HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\*.*", &fd);

  if (h !=  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    BOOL b;
    do {
      if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
          printf("d: %S\n", fd.cFileName);
      //else
      //    printf("f: %S\n", fd.cFileName);

      b = FindNextFile(h, &fd);
    } while (b != FALSE);
    FindClose(h);
  }
}
```

The output I am getting is pretty much what you would expect:

```
d: .
d: ..
d: AutoRecover
d: en-US
d: Logs
d: Repository
d: tmf
d: xml
```

However, from a command prompt in c:\Windows\System32\wbem, `dir /ad` gives me:

```
06/15/2016  07:20 PM    <DIR>          .
06/15/2016  07:20 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/14/2016  05:40 PM    <DIR>          AutoRecover
03/24/2011  03:52 PM    <DIR>          en-US
07/13/2009  06:34 PM    <DIR>          Logs
07/13/2009  09:08 PM    <DIR>          MOF
02/20/2017  10:32 PM    <DIR>          Performance
02/23/2017  03:59 AM    <DIR>          Repository
07/13/2009  06:36 PM    <DIR>          tmf
07/13/2009  07:20 PM    <DIR>          xml
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  171,203,104,768 bytes free
```

A close examination reveals that the `Performance` and `MOF` directories are not listed in my output.  Huh?

Clearly something is different about these directories.  But what?

- Looking at the `dir` output, we can see that they are not junctions.
- Using attrib, there aren't any special flags set (like system or hidden).
- fsutil doesn't show any hard links.
- Looking at the directory permissions, Administrators (which I am) have full control.

I'm stumped.  I've even gone so far as to run `chkdsk /f` to see if my directory tables are screwed up.  Other than some `Cleaning up 472 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9. Cleaning up 472 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.` it didn't find anything.

I've tried using FindFileEx with various options, but I still can't get these directories to appear.

I can't think what else to try.  What would cause these directories to appear for `dir` but not for `FindFile`?  And (more importantly) how can I get them to appear in FindFile?

FWIW:

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Drive C is NTFS
- Building with MSVC 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to access the 64-bit `System32` folder.

I'm guessing your code is compiled as 32-bit, thus you would actually be accessing the 32-bit `SysWOW64` folder instead due to the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx). On my Win7 x64 machine, the missing folders (`MOF` and `Performance`) only exist in the 64-bit `System32\wbem` folder, but not in the 32-bit `SysWOW64\wbem` folder.

If 32-bit code wants to access the 64-bit `System32` folder, it has to use WOW64's special `Sysnative` alias to avoid redirection, eg:

```
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\wbem\\*.*", &fd);
```

Use [`IsWow64Process()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139.aspx) to know if your code is running inside of the WOW64 emulator or not.

With that said, you should not hard-code the `c:\\Windows` path, either.  Not all users install Windows to that path.  Use [`GetWindowsDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454.aspx), [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_WINDOWS)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx), or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Windows)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) instead to get the actual path.

Try something more like this:

```
bool IsRunningInWow64()
{
    #ifndef _WIN64
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
    if (IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64) && bIsWow64)
        return true;
    #endif

    return false;
}

...

WCHAR szMask[MAX_PATH];

if (IsRunningInWow64())
{
    // Must be a 32-bit process running on a 64-bit system.
    // Use the 'Sysnative' alias...

    GetWindowsDirectory(szMask, MAX_PATH);
    // or: SHGetFolderPath(..., CSIDL_WINDOWS, ...);
    // or: SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Windows, ...);
    PathAppend(szMask, L"Sysnative");
}
else
{
    // Must be either:
    // - A 32-bit process running on a 32-bit system.
    // - A 64-bit process running on a 64-bit system.
    // Use the standard 'System32' path...

    GetSystemDirectory(szMask, MAX_PATH);
    // or: SHGetFolderPath(..., CSIDL_SYSTEM, ...);
    // or: SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_System, ...);
}

PathAppend(szMask, L"wbem");
PathAppend(szMask, L"*.*");

HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(szMask, &fd);
```

Comment: Doh!  Yup, sure enough, I was building 32bit.  The directories it was reporting were from syswow64.  The wbem directory there does not include these 2 directories.